# Make Github actions job wait for CircleCI workflow

Tags: github-actions, circleci

My repository has CircleCI workflows setup to perform various actions including building a container image for the service. I also have an existing workflow using GitHub actions from another repository that I would like to migrate to this repository. My Job in GitHub actions requires the container image that is currently built by CircleCI. It is important that both of these workflows run on pull requests since they need to access information about the PR that triggered the workflow and post comments.

Ideally I would like both workflows to behave as they normally do with the GitHub actions workflow simply waiting for the CircleCI workflow to finish before it starts. Is there a way to accomplish this or have the GitHub actions workflow read the status of the CircleCI workflow to check if it has completed or not?

If I could not find a way for the GitHub actions workflow to wait was to have the GitHub actions workflow run a loop to check if it can pull the container image it is expecting and if not then sleep until a successful pull. This isn't a great solution and would needlessly waste CI minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to trigger the GitHub action workflow from the CircleCI Workflow by [create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event). You can use the following curl command to trigger the workflow or you could also use [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api):

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo_name>/actions/workflows/<workflow>/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"ref"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had seen another similar question where this solution worked for them, but as I mentioned I would like to have the github action be triggered by the pull request event so that I can access information about the event such as `export PULL_NUM=$(jq --raw-output .pull_request.number "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH")`

Comment: You can simply put these information in the body as inputs and can use it in the workflow.